# What is the meaning of "the more" in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Algae are living things that corals eat. ***The more*** the corals have to eat, the larger their reefs will grow.

I think "**the corals**" is the **subject** of the sentence "the more the corals have to eat", but how about "the more". Does it mean algae? Can I reverse the sentence into the corals have to eat more, the larger their reefs will grow?

Comment: Have a look https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-comparative-correlative-grammar-1689769 It's a common pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep similar grammatical relationships, you can't reverse that phrasing:

> The more [that] the corals have to eat, the larger [that] their reefs will grow.

In the original (meaning without any "that") we have two *contact clauses*.  Those are relative clauses which work even though there is no word like "that" or "which" to introduce them.

If you think that sentences must have subjects, I have a sentence for you: "Horsefeathers and balderdash."   Actually, I can provide another: "Hello."   My point here is that subjects don't belong directly to sentences.   Rather, they belong to clauses, existing as a part of a subject/predicate pairing.   Sentences can and usually do contain clauses which contain subjects, but the idea of *"the subject of the sentence"* falls apart when you're working with compound sentences, complex sentences, and nominal sentences like "the more, the merrier" and "the bigger, the better".   A sentence might contain several subjects, or it might contain no subject at all.

We can paraphrase the original as a condition/consequence pairing expressed in a complex sentence structure:

> If the corals have more to eat, then their reefs will grow larger.

The semantics here are substantially the same, despite the grammatical differences.   It's not *quite* as simple a transformation as merely restoring an inversion to its canonical order.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the [Correlative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)#Correlative_conjunctions) construction "the [comparative], the [comparative]".

The two *the's* are both required, and the comparatives (adjectives or adverbs) must occur at the beginning of their respective clauses.

It is saying that Whenever the corals have more to eat, their reefs will grow larger.

Other examples are

> The longer he stays there, the more tired he will get.

> The quicker you finish, the happier I will be.